# Java bounded parameters in generic methods

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have tested some things with bounded parameters in generic methods and I discovered some strange behavior.
It would be great If anybody could explain the two errors in the following code snippet.

Imagine there are two classes `Class1` and `Class2` both extend from a `BaseClass`.  `Class2` implements an Interface.

In `Class1`, I have a method which returns an instance of `Class2` in the following way:

```
public class Class2 extends BaseClass implements Interface {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("test"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
}

public class Class1 extends BaseClass {

    public <T extends BaseClass & Interface> T getTwo() {
        return new Class2();
        // Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class2 to T
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface two = new Class1().getTwo();
        // Error: Bound mismatch: The generic method getTwo() of type Class1 is
        // not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type Interface is
        // not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends BaseClass
        // & Interface>
        System.out.println(two);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like misuse of generics. Actually `getTwo` must have return type just `Class2`, or `BaseClass`, or `Interface`. If `T` is defined only for one method there is no way for compiler to know which class exactly substitutes `T` at the line `new Class1().getTwo()`. It would only be possible if `getTwo` would have input parameters of this type.

Answer (score 5):

The first compilation error occurs because type parameters declared by methods are specified by the caller, not the method implementation. That is, given

```
class Class3 extends BaseClass implements Interface { ... }
```

a caller may write

```
Class3 c3 = new Class1().<Class3>getTwo();
```

, but the method implementation returns a `Class2`, which isn't a subtype of `T` = `Class3`.

The second compilation error occurs because type parameters that aren't explicitly specified by the caller are inferred from method arguments and the type of the variable the method return value is assigned to. This inference fails here. The usual workaround, recommended by the Java Language Specification, is to specify the type parameters explicitly in such cases (type inference is intended as a convenience for simple cases; it doesn't aim to cover all cases).

As for how to properly declare this type parameter, I'd need to know what you are trying to accomplish with these declarations.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I think the syntax would be `new Class1().<Class3>getTwo()` in your second code example though.

Comment: I see the point for the first compilation error, but I'm quite unsure about the second.
The call `BaseClass two = new Class1().getTwo();` seems to be OK on my system but fails on a colleague's system and the call 
`Interface two = new Class1().getTwo();` fails on my system, too (as shown above)...

Comment: Well, have you tried specifying the type parameter explictly, analogously to my `Class3` example? Or tweaking type inference by declaring `Class2 two = new Class1().getTwo();`? I can't explain off-hand why it would behave differently on your system. Have you tried the exact same example programs with the same compiler with the same settings?

Comment: Imagine the "getwo()"-Method is part of an Interface and you don't know the exact return type of getTwo, you want to use the returned object in a generic way. Do you know why 
'BaseClass two = class1.getTwo();' is OK and 
'Interface two = class1.getTwo();' cannot be compiled?

Comment: Ok, I imagine that. I'd probably define `abstract class BaseClassWithInterface extends BaseClass implements Interface {}` and require `Class2` to extend it. Any caller could then use a variable of `BaseClassWithInterface` to store the object. About your why question: Probably because the algorithm [specified in section 15.12.2.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#341287) of the Java Language Specification says so.

Comment: Ah, Ok this is how the Type Inference works right? I could either define a `BaseClassWithInterface` as you described or define the Interface with a generic parameter. I think I got a deeper insight into generics in java. Thanks Marco

Answer (score 4):

Why use generics for the method `getTwo`, when you *know* it's a `Class2`? Simply do this:

```
public Class2 getTwo() {
    return new Class2();
}
```

If you're overriding a method `public <T extends BaseClass & Interface> T getTwo()`, the compiler will allow you to declare your impl as `public Class2 getTwo()` when your `T` for your impl is `Class2`

Comment: Not so fast on that override.  In your scenario you would be overriding a method that could return any T satisfying the constraint with one that returned Class2, which should be disallowed for the same reason the OP's code was disallowed.  I am not sure Java can even express a return type with an existential quantifier.